# Not able to create IOS build from Xcode using Flutter code?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using Windows for Flutter app development and it is working fine for android ,I want to know how can I create IOS build from XCode now.? Does it required to do full flutter setup with Xcode on Mac or I can build it with Xcode only ? Apology for my terrible english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build an iOS project you have to install XCode on your MAC with flutter and dart Installations, and if you don't have MAC you can run your code from any browser from [flutlab.io](https://flutlab.io/)

Comment: Can i install on my windows? could you please share a link for it?

Comment: Please do not suggest illegal actions here.  You cannot run macos on anything other than genuine mac hardware.  The license you accepted by using the software says so.

Answer (score 1):

You need XCode + Flutter installation on a Mac to create iOS build.
XCode alone will not work. You will have to clone your project into the Mac & then open the project in Xcode to create the build.

Comment: He said he running on windows operating system. how could he got an Mac device?

Comment: By getting one.  Or using codemagic.io, but really hard to debug that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode only works on Mac. And yes you have to do a full flutter setup with Xcode on Mac which is not so difficult, you will find many flutter setup with Xcode video in youtube.